# page curl effect

Tags: web

currently i am working on a website and the client requires page curl effect in the top right corner of the page.What will be the best resource for this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look here

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/5-extremely-simple-ways-to-add-page-curl-to-your-website/

My personal favorite would be using jQuery.

Let us know if this is what you were looking for.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You could just have stacked images (2 static gifs and animated gif) and when they hover over the image it creates the curling effect in the corner.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the page curl as an image in an image editor such as Gimp or Photoshop (others also available).  You can then add it to your website either as the background image of a div via CSS (the preferred method) or via an img tag in the HTML document.